# I have written a python code for identifying leap year. It works perfectly but the code seems a bit off

Tags: python-3.x

I have written a code for identifying leap year. It works perfectly but the code seems a bit off. I have added the code here. Plz someone confirm whether the code is correct or not.

the code

```
year = int(input("Which year do you want to check? "))
divided_by_4 = year % 4
divided_by_100 = year % 100
divided_by_400 = year % 400
if divided_by_4 == 0 and divided_by_400 == 0 or divided_by_100 != 0:
  print("It is a leap year.")
else:
  print("Not a leap year.")
```

Comment: Can you explain "a bit off"?  Does it produce wrong results for some years?  If so, say which years are wrong

Comment: no, it produces correct results for all the years I input. by a bit off I actually mean stuff in head. otherwise, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

A year is not a leap year if it is divisible by 100, unless it is divisible by 400, so you should test `divided_by_100 != 0` first and then use the `or` operator to test `divided_by_400 == 0` as a fallback. Since `or` has a lower operator precedence than `and`, you should enclose the `or` operation in parentheses:

```
if divided_by_4 == 0 and (divided_by_100 != 0 or divided_by_400 == 0):
    print("It is a leap year.")
else:
    print("Not a leap year.")
```